# Intel vs AMD for laptop compatibility

Tags: laptop, cpu, compatibility

My past three laptops were all Intel CPU powered but this time I'm considering a model that is AMD chip driven.

I see other threads that compare AMD vs Intel for performance etc. but that doesn't interest me as much as absolute incompatibility: i.e. Are there still programs / software that will refuse to run on AMD cpus?

Any examples of packages that won't run on an AMD cpu laptop? Just wanted to see if there's a list out there that I could compare to my use case.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the architecture (32-bit or 64-bit) is compatible any program that runs on Intel hardware can and will run on AMD hardware too. Only exception I know of is the OSX86 project which probably doesn't count because it's a hack of Apple software which is designed to run on Intel CPUs only.